# How to save screen output in a file?

Tags: gnu-screen

I am running a python script within a `screen` session for hours which is printing messages on the terminal. I want all that output in a file for debugging purpose. How do I it

Just to clear, the screen is already running.

Comment: In the screen session type: `Ctrl-a` + `H` (the `H` must be uppercase). That will redirect the output to a file too.

Comment: You can also use `gdb` command to redirect **stdout/stderr** of some proccess to a file.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I tried CTL+A but it just logged what was currently visible, not all since the beginning of the session

Comment: Oh you are right! So I think the `gdb` method will not work too. Not sure if redirect the previous output of already running process is possible, I will try to take a look too.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thanks, Sir. I am looking something like redirecting Cron output to a file...

Comment: You could turn your script into a `systemd` service.  Then you can run things remotely and it'll all get logged in the journal for you.

Comment: @Stewart According to the user, the script is already running.

Comment: @Stewart I am using shared hosting

Comment: @Volatil3 that doesn't preclude systemd user units and timers, at all.